# Having issues setting up SSL/TSL on Windows 10 64bit ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: ssl, https, windows-10, apache2.4

So my website works just fine with http even on devices outside of my network.

https, on the other hand, only works on the very machine the server is hosted on. Trying to connect via a VPN or trying to connect from my phone (on the same network) will result in the following error:

```
This website can’t provide a secure connection

ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I tried disabling firewall, disabling antivirus software, reinstalling Apache, using XAMPP instead of WAMP, opening port 443, none of it works. Still getting the same error. I am running Apache 2.4 inside of WAMP on a Windows 10 64 bit machine.

My virtualhosts:

```
Listen 443
Listen 80

<VirtualHost _default_:443> 
ServerName example.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateKeyFile c:/certbot/live/example.com/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateFile c:/certbot/live/example.com/cert.pem
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
DocumentRoot f:/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory f:/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog c:/wamp64/logs/errorSSL.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog c:/wamp64/logs/accessSSL.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  DocumentRoot "f:/www"
  <Directory "f:/www">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So what is going on here? What am I doing incorrectly? Any help will be appreciated.